# Remove elements created dynamically in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have list of profiles being shown in a colorbox window. Each item in the list have a "+" button to add them to the final list. 
I have added a check (if($('#id').length == 0)) to check if the element is already in the final list and prevent it from adding twice in the list.

Everything works fine when colorbox is loaded first time. But when colorbox is closed and reopened the if condition fails because the element was not destroyed on $.colorbox.close event. The element is still present in the the document, but would not be shown in the colorbox window because the content has been reloaded from an external url. This shows me the alert box "This Member is already in the list" even when "final-list" empty.

```
$(document).on('click', "a.add_to_list", function() {
    var new_id = 'final_'+$(this).data('id');
    var html = '<li id="'+new_id+'"><a data-id="'+new_id+'" class="remove label label-important right "><i class="icon-minus icon-white"></i></a>' + $('#'+id).html() + '</li>';
    if($('#'+new_id).length == 0) {
        $('#final_list').append(html);  
    }
    else
    {
        alert('This Member is already in the list');
    }       
});

 $(document).on('click', "a.remove", function() {
    remove_id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#'+remove_id).remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="list1"><li id="user1"><a class="right add_to_list label label-important" data-id="'user1'"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></a><a href="http://localhost/test/profile/user1" class="align-left">
  <img width="60px" height="60px" src="http://localhost/test/files/profile_img/user1.jpg" class="avatar photo"></a><p>User 1</a><br>@user1<br>Description</p></li></ul>
```

Elements added in final list

```
<ul id="final-list"><li id="final-user1"><a class="right remove label label-important" data-id="final_user1"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></a><a href="http://localhost/test/profile/user1" class="align-left">
      <img width="60px" height="60px" src="http://localhost/test/files/profile_img/user1.jpg" class="avatar photo"></a><p>User 1</a><br>@user1<br>Description</p></li></ul>
```

Now I want to destroy the elements on colorbox.close event so that they should not be present in the document when the colorbox is opened for the second time.
I tried changing the colorbox.close event's execution from close() method to remove() method.
It did the job, but it removes the complete colorbox element, which prevents opening the colorbox again until you reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, I found the the problem for this issue. 
I have added the jQuery code inside the "onComplete" function of colorbox. 
Now, after loading the colorbox second time, same jquery code is added to the document again which causes the click event to fire twice.

Now I have two options,

1. Use code outside the onComplete function of the colorbox. (I cannot get the code working this way).
2. Remove the jquery code loaded while closing the colorbox.

Kindly, find me a solution to sort out this problem.

Comment: The problem has been solved by using the first option, to add the code outside the onComplete option of colorbox, which prevented from loading the jquery code twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', "a.remove", function() {
 remove_id = $(this).data('id');
 $('#'+remove_id).remove();
});
```

Use this.. $(this).data('id') already contains 'final_'. Dont need to append it again

Comment: sorry for the confusion bro, but I missed some part which was deleted accidentally before posting. Now it's added again.

My motive is to destroy the new list item ID's when colorbox is closed. Everything else works fine.